# Parsing html in Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to parse the fragments of html like this:

```
<div><span>adrress</span>text of address</div>
```

How can I take fragment 'text of address' programatically without span tag in Beatiful soup?

Now I take whole content of div and remove span, but I think there are a better way

Comment: is it possible to use regexp ?

Comment: @tanaydin regexp and html do not go together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> fragment = '<div><span>adrress</span>text of address</div>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(fragment)
>>> soup.div.span.nextSibling
u'text of address'
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = "<div><span>address</span>text of address</div>"
>>> print BeautifulSoup(text).find('div').contents[-1]
text of address
```

Sorry for my first answer, I misread the question.